# How do I know if was require_once?

Tags: php

I have two files

**1 - index.php
2 - main.php**

**index.php** call to **main.php** by `<?php require_once("../../includes/main.php"); ?>`

How do I know from **main.php** when it executes,

if **index.php** calls to him or the same user executes it Standalone?
What should I ask inside main php to continue running the program if was require_once?

Comment: If you're worried about a file being invoked directly by a remote user, then keep that file outside of your web document root. Can't remotely invoke files that you can't access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use `get_included_files()` - the "main" file that included the other ones will always show up on top = be the 0th element of the returned array:

```
if (get_included_files()[0] !== __FILE__) {
    // ..included
} else {
    // ..not included
}
```

This will work in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I have done that before by setting a variable before the include, then doing the include.  For example:

```
$included_main_from = 'index.php';
require ('../../includes/main.php');
```

Then in main.php just check for that variable and what its value is.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of frameworks define a constant in `index.php`, and in `main.php` you can check it's existence with `defined()`. You could get more info with the debug backtrace function, but you shouldn't use that in production / for inspection.