# The opposite of require?

Tags: php

Is is possible for a php script to know if another script calls it via require or require_once?

eg:

```
if scripta.php calls me do xyz;
if scriptb.php calls me do abc;
```

*Edit: Thanks for your suggestions guys. It was more of a what if question, rather than an actual problem. I realise I could set a variable, $caller and update it when I made the require statement. I just wondered if there was another way to do this in the file that's being called :)*

Comment: Yes, kind of, but it's usually not the ideal way architecture-wise to do things. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: You might want to consider refactoring the script to contain functions and then calling the appropriate one from each.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know if was require_once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106938/how-do-i-know-if-was-require-once)

Comment: If you stumbled upon a problem that requires you to obtain nearly impossible information, that's a hint of a bad design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you just want to check if the your file was included or not:**

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will always return the filename of the script that has been originally called. (e.g. "start.php")

The constant `__FILE__` will always return the true file name of the script that it is used in. (e.g. "library.inc.php")

So you can do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] !== __FILE__) {
    echo "script was included!";
}
else {
    echo "script was called directly!";
}
```

**If you want to distinguish from where the file has been included:**

```
$include_from = get_included_files();
if (count($include_from) > 1) {
    $include_from = $include_from[count($include_from)-2];
}
else {
    $include_from = $include_from[0];
}
switch ($include_from) {
    case __FILE__:
        // not included, called directly
        break;
    case "/path/to/scripta.php":
        // do abc
        break;
    case "/path/to/scriptb.php": 
        // do xyz
        break;
    default:
        // do other stuff
        break;
}
```

Comment: Note that get_included_files() returns absolute filenames. Furthermore, the last element will most likely be the current file as it also got included and therefore got appended to the list. Also, this method gives you nothing more than a candidate, because the "includer" may actually have been included earlier.

Comment: @Niko the last element is the file that included the current script. i have tested the code before posting it. Regarding absolute file names you are absolutely right, this is just an example.

Comment: PHP 5.3.8 reports differently for me: Master.php `<?php include 'Slave.php';`, Slave.php `<?php print_r(get_included_files());`, `php Master.php` prints an array containing both files. Your test was probably successful because you mixed up array_shift() with array_pop().

Comment: @Niko no it was successfull because `array_shift()` gets the first element of the array, being `Master.php` in your example. However, i realized this is wrong when the include path is deeper (e.g. master.php->sub1.php->sub2.php). I addressed the issues you raised in my latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the files in the order in which they have been included via [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/get_included_files) (returns an array of the filenames).

- The main file that was executed is always the 0th element.
- If you're looking for the file that included the current file, the last but one element is your candidate.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [get_included_files](https://www.php.net/get_included_files) (or `get_required_files`):

```
if(in_array($my_file, get_included_files())
{
    // do something
}
```

Replace `$my_file` with the file you need to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Example:

If you use debug_backtrace() on an included file :

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["file"]=> string(71) "/home/index.php"
        ["line"]=> int(3)
        ["function"]=> string(7) "require"
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you should post links to english resources (though the language of this one is easy to change).

Comment: +1, I think it's the best option to reverse engineered the execution flow.

Comment: @Florent that is just dumb.  *It doesn't do what the OP wants.*

Comment: Yes it does. You just need to iterate the backtrace looking for `file` key. If the specified file is founded, then it was included.

Comment: @Florent If what djidi shows above is correct (I'm testing it right now, I was pretty sure it wasn't possible), then I indeed stand corrected. Sorry. Still, `debug_backtrace()` is very slow and not a good way to do this in a production environment.

Comment: Indeed, this works. Removing my downvote. As said, I still don't recommend this.

Comment: **@Pekka** I agree with you, It's slow and bad practice but the OP seems to try to audit his code. In that case, debugging instructions may be slow but will be likely removed (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is defining constants.

Calling script:

```
define("SCRIPT_NAME", "script_a.php");
```

And in the called script:

```
if(defined("SCRIPT_NAME") && SCRIPT_NAME == "script_a.php") {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: would be better to have a solution where not every file must be touched.

Answer (score 0):

a require is nothing else then a code snipped loaded into the exact place the require or require_once call is called.

if you really want to know what exact file is calling it, you could do it relative dirty and assign a variable before the call and check inside your script what kind of value it has

e.g.

```
$require_reference = "main.php";
require_once ("some_script.php");
```

now inside the some_script.php you do something like this:

```
if (isset($require_reference) && $require_reference == "main.php")
{ 
    // dome something 
}
```

this will work but it is really messy. Maybe you should try to refactor your design